# I have a problem with date and something wrong with checking the messages

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I wanted to create a IELTS test taker bot on python. 
Now, I tell you the work of the bot:
First of all, when user starts the test, bot gives a speaking questions.
After the speaking questions, bot gives listening test. In fact, there will be given 40 minutes to user to send the answers to the bot. And if user sends the answer, bot checks it and gives reading tests
Whether or not user sends answers to the listening test in 40 minutes, bot must send the reading tests and give 60 minutes to user to send the answers. After 60 minutes, bot sends the writing test.
After all, bot must check the answers, which are sent by user at the test time.

Problem is I can't check the answers from the user.
Here is my code. PLEASE HELP ME:

````
import telebot
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

bot = telebot.TeleBot("**")

now = datetime.now() #Time when test start
lb=now + timedelta(minutes=10) #Listening test start time
rb=now + timedelta(minutes=50) #Reading test start time
wb=now + timedelta(minutes=110) #Writing test start time

ls=0 #Listening score
rs=0 #Reading score

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello. I will begin with speaking.")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Speaking test end")
    s=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Listening test. Send the answers within 40 minutes")
**Problem is here** 
   while datetime.now()!=rb: #I mean until reading begin, make it possible to 
       bot.register_next_step_handler(s, l_answers)
    if datetime.now()==rb: #Here I mean if user does not send the answers within 40 mins, move on to reading test
        k=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Reading test...")

        if datetime.now()!=wb: #until writing begin, make it possible to receive answers for reading
            bot.register_next_step_handler(k, r_answers)
    elif datetime.now()==wb:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "I'm sending Writing test...")
        time.sleep(3600)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"exam is finished. Click results to see your band score: \n /results")


def l_answers(message): #receiving answers for lisening tests and checking it
    ans = message.text.split("\n")
    answers = [a.split(".")[1].strip() for a in ans]
    right_answers = [
    {'Localhost'},
    {'General'}
    ]

    ls=0
    for user, right in zip(answers, right_answers):
        if user in right:
            ls+=1

    while datetime.now()==rb: #if it is time to start reading, send the reading tests
        k=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Reading test...")

        if datetime.now()!=wb: 
            bot.register_next_step_handler(k, r_answers)
    elif datetime.now()==wb:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Writing test...")
        time.sleep(60)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Click results to see your band score: \n /results")

def r_answers(message): #receiving answers for reading tests and checking it
    ans = message.text.split("\n")
    answers = [a.split(".")[1].strip() for a in ans]
    right_answers = [
    {'Localhost'},
    {'General'}
    ]


    for user, right in zip(answers, right_answers):
        if user in right:
            rs+=1

    if datetime.now()==wb:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Writing test...")
        time.sleep(60)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Click results to see your band score: \n /results")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['results'])
def send_welcomre(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Listening correct answers"+ls)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Reading correct answers"+rs) 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
````

Comment: 'Something wrong' is a much too vague description of your problem. You have to be much more specific for your question to be on-topic on SO.

Comment: can you be more specific on what is the problem with your code?

Comment: simple words, do you want to get difference of times and compare that with a period ..??